# Writing to DB failed?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write 2 data to db.

```
  @IBAction func show(button: UIButton) {

        let userRef = self.dataBaseRef.child("users/\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)")
        userRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)
            let currentUser = user.email
            let request = Requests(requestBy: user.email!,
                                   requestTo: self.email!)

            let contactRef = self.ref.child(currentUser! + "--" + self.email!)
            contactRef.setValue(request.toAnyObject())
            self.items.append(request)
            print(request)
        }) { (error ) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);

}
```

items is an array

```
var items: [Requests] = []
```

user.email and self.email! isn't empty I printed it.

request file looks

```
struct Requests {

let key: String
let requestBy: String
let requestTo: String
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

init(requestBy: String, requestTo: String, key: String = "") {
    self.key = key
    self.requestBy = requestBy
    self.requestTo = requestTo
    self.ref = nil
}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    requestBy = snapshotValue["requestBy"] as! String
    requestTo = snapshotValue["requestTo"] as! String
    ref = snapshot.ref
}

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return [
        "requestBy": requestBy,
        "requestTo": requestTo
    ]
}
```

}

and I'm getting error - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Where it breaks? I see that the first piece of code is in a closure. but it is cut. Would you please include the whole code? thank you.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza I've edited it.

Comment: could you add in which line it crashed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let currentUser = user.email  //this is not an optional
let request = Requests(requestBy: user.email!,
                                   requestTo: self.email!)

contactRef = self.ref.child(currentUser! + "--" + self.email!)
```

currentUser! doesn't need to be unwrapped.

Answer (score 2):

According to what I'm seeing in your posted code, you create a request but never assign a value to the ref property. However, it is not clear since we cannot see where it crashes or when is it really used.

Also, assuming self.ref is an optional (as you've been handled that way in your visible code) then this could be the problem:

let contactRef = self.ref.child

you should first check if you can unwrap that optional, like:

`if let realRef = self.ref {
realRef.child(currentUser! + "--" + self.email!)
}`

Comment: I've posted full code of button.. It crash when I press the button.

Comment: According to this line:
let request = Requests(requestBy: user.email!,
                                   requestTo: self.email!)
the email property in your user is optional so you are unwrapping it there. But in the previous line you didn't. So I suggest you first check if you really have all your values, for instance:
if let email = user.email {
//Put all your code that needs that email here
}